# C: Structs and array - overview and help needed

Tags: c

in my phase of (re)learning C, I'm often facing problems with arrays and structures (and pointers). This is a little test I wrote.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char name[10];
} man;

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int i;
    man john;
    strcpy(john.name, "john");

    // array of structures
    man men[10];
    strcpy(men[3].name, "john");
    printf("*** %s ***\n", men[3].name);

    // dynamic array of structures
    man *men2;
    men2 = malloc(10 * sizeof(man));
    strcpy(men2[3].name, "john");
    printf("*** %s ***\n", men2[3].name);

    // multidimensional array of structures
    man men3[10][10];
    strcpy(men3[3][3].name, "john");
    printf("*** %s ***\n", men3[3][3].name);

    // dynamic multidimensional array of structures
    man **men4;
    men4 = malloc(10 * sizeof(man*));
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        men4[i] = malloc(10 * sizeof(man*));
    strcpy(men4[3][3].name, "john");
    printf("*** %s ***\n", men4[3][3].name);

    // array of pointer to structure
    man *men5[10];
    men5[3] = &john;
    printf("*** %s ***\n", men5[3]->name);

    // dynamic array of pointers to structure
    man **men6;
    men6 = malloc(10 * sizeof(*men6));
    men6[3] = &john;
    printf("*** %s ***\n", men6[3]->name);  

    // dynamic multidimensional array of pointers to structures
    /* ? */

    return 0;
}
```

Can you:

1. tell me if all is correct
2. explain why in men4 i use `sizeof(man*)` but in men6 it is `sizeof(*men6)` (asterisk position)
3. explain how to make a dynamic multidimensional array of pointers to structures (last point)
4. explain me men4? it works, but is seems to me more of an array of pointers to structure than a multidimensional array of structures!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your these two cases

```
// dynamic multidimensional array of structures
man **men4;
men4 = malloc(10 * sizeof(man*));
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    men4[i] = malloc(10 * sizeof(man*));
```

and

```
// dynamic array of pointers to structure
man **men6;
men6 = malloc(10 * sizeof(*men6));
men6[3] = &john;
printf("*** %s ***\n", men6[3]->name);
```

are conceptually the same.  In both cases, you have a pointer to a pointer to `man`.  You are using those pointers differently.  Also, the first one has an error. Instead of:

```
    men4[i] = malloc(10 * sizeof(man*));
```

you should have written:

```
    men4[i] = malloc(10 * sizeof(man));
```

because each `men4[i]` is of type "pointer to `man`".  That error is why I usually prefer my `malloc()` calls to be of the form:

```
a = malloc(N * sizeof *a);
```

So, your call would have become:

```
men4[i] = malloc(10 * sizeof *men4[i]);
```

This is less error-prone.

So, the answer to your question (2) is, you should have use `sizeof(man *)` only when allocating for `men4`, but not inside the loop.  (Or, you now know a better way to call `malloc()`, so the call outsize the loop becomes `men4 = malloc(10 * sizeof *men4);`.)

1. It is all correct, except for the `malloc()` call as mentioned above.
2. See above.
3. You want an array of pointers to struct.  To get an array, you need `[]`, since it is a pointer to a pointer that you want (multidimensional), you want two `**`.  So you get: `man **(men7[10]);`, but since `[]` binds more tightly than `*` anyway, you can write it as `man **men7[10];`.
4. `men4` is not a multidimensional array nor an array of pointers.  It is a pointer to a pointer to `man`.  When you allocate memory for `men4`, you allocate space for 10 pointers to `man`.  Then, each pointer is allocated space for 10 `man`.  The fact that you can index `men4` as a multidimensional array is a result of such allocation.  In your loop, each `men4[i]` could have been allocated space for different number of `man` values if you would have liked, something which is impossible to do with multidimensional arrays.

Pointers are not arrays.  Arrays are not pointers.  Please read all the questions and answers in [section 6 of the C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

- 2: These are two examples that do the same thing: `sizeof(*men6) == sizeof(man*)`!
- 3: Same as the men5 example, but multidimensional.
- 4: The men4 example is not quite correct. As far as I understand what it should mean, that example must read:

---

```
man ***men4; // 10x10 multidimensional
men4 = malloc(10 * sizeof(man**));
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    men4[i] = malloc(10 * sizeof(man*));
    for(j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
        men4[i][j] = malloc(sizeof(man));
}    
strcpy(men4[3][3]->name, "john");
printf("*** %s ***\n", men4[3][3]->name);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Semantically correct
2. It **IS** an array of pointers, so you have to allocate pointer-sized elements, and size of pointer is `sizeof(void*)` which is equal to `sizeof(man*)`
3. `man ***men;`
4. Yes, it is. Should be `man **men[10];`